# Session Persistence with Nginx as Reverse Proxy?

Tags: nginx

I am using NGINX as a reverse proxy with two Apache Servers as upstream servers.

Both of the Apache Server has custom PHP application installed and share same MYSQL Database.

I believe Apache stores sessions in /var/lib/sessions.

If I am using NGINX, how to overcome the Session related issue ? I understand the ip_hash; but is that the only feasible way ?

Was wondering on how people solve this issue on their server side ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strictly speaking, this has nothing to do with nginx, this is a task to provide users a consistent authentication/authorizing system across multiple backends. Instead of nginx you can use any load-balancing engine.

Standard approach:

- use memcached to store sessions (although this isn't recommended by memcache authors, this method is largely used, and even PHP has standard support for it - you need to uncomment one line in php.ini)
- use redis for same purpose
- recent versions of MySQL provide [memcached-identical interface to store sessions in MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-memcached.html) (this time they will be disk-backed)- use whatever you like for this, the only thing - it should be a centralized storage

Comment: I have a centralized Database which my upstream servers use. So will storing Session in MySQL be a good option in this case ?

Comment: Depends on the amount of sessions, because memcached, without disk-backing can be faster on large amounts, but generally - yes.